# Deleting Widgets in sidebar in Panthea theme

Tags: themes

How can I delete the side widgets in WP Panthea theme. I have Search, Archives, Categories and Blog roll. I am used to HTML but am lost in Php. Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the default widgets in Wordpress? If these widgets is specific to your theme you are using, then your question is off topic

Answer (score 1):

Generaly using admin panel you can remove side bar widget go to `Apperance=>widgets` in that you wil see the name Main sidebar name in that box you will have the sidebar click and drag through left side or click and delete it. This is based for all the themes check it let you know for any doubts.